# Is there a standard vertical datum for meters below the WGS84 ellipsoid, or below MSL?

Tags: wms, epsg

I have data I am publishing a WMS layer representing data under the surface of the water, say temperature at 100m depth.  What is the accepted way to represent this in WMS GetCapabilities document?

Do I define the dimension like:

```
<Dimension name="elevation" 
           units="EPSG:5030" 
           unitSymbol="m">0,50,100</Dimension>
```

or

```
<Dimension name="elevation" 
           units="EPSG:5030" 
           unitSymbol="m">0,-50,-100</Dimension>
```

or something else or should a custom dimension be used in this case?

<s>EPSG:5030 is a length parameter, it doesn't indicate that it's related to any projection or that it might indicate distance from mean sea level for that matter. see http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/wiki/VerticalCS</s>
EPSG:5030 represents height *above* the WGS85 ellipsoid. I found a [reference to EPSG:5715](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/5715/), but it doesn't say much other than it's 'msl depth' - does this mean values below msl should be positive?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some further reading, it looks like the specifics of which orientation *z* values increase in depends on the specific vertical coordinate system (VCS) being used. Vertical systems oriented with 'z up' are height-based VCSes, as opposed to depth-based VCS where z is down. EPSG:5715 is an example of one such depth-based system, which when examined [in the EPSG registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org/) includes this information:

> Vertical CS. Axis: depth (D).
>   Orientation: down. UoM: m

The ArcGIS 10 [help on vertical coordinate systems](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003r00000014000000.htm) similarly states:

> Another important part is whether the z-values represent heights (elevations) or depths. 
>   For each type, the z-axis direction is positive "up" or "down," respectively.

Finally, a [proposed revision to the ISO 19111 standard](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=6716) includes this information on vertical datums:

> 4.55
>   **vertical datum** 
>   Datum describing the relation of gravity-related
>   heights or depths to the Earth 
>   
>   NOTE
>   In most cases the vertical datum will be
>   related to mean sea level. Ellipsoidal
>   heights are treated as related to a
>   three-dimensional ellipsoidal
>   coordinate system referenced to a
>   geodetic datum. Vertical datums
>   include sounding datums (used for
>   hydrographic purposes), in which case
>   the heights may be negative heights or
>   depths.

Comment: you mean no clients parse the elevation parameter?  also i edited my question a bit, maybe this would help clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi Dave, I've rewritten my answer with further information. I had meant that no WMS clients I'm aware of explicitly parse the dimensions to determine if the CS is depth or height based, cheers

Comment: Nice answer.  The proposed ISO revision was news to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For depth below the surface of the water there is [EPSG:5831](http://epsg.io/5831), and [ESPG:5829](http://epsg.io/5829) for heights above.

If you have a buoy floating on the sea with a temperature sensor dangling 100m below, you could describe it as at "Depth" of 100m w.r.t. EPSG:5831, or a "Height" at -100m w.r.t. EPSG:5829